# Adobe Air-electrical signature between the previous certificate and the recent certificate

Tags: air, certificate, adobe, migrate

there!
I hard that here is the numerous genius in this service.
I appreciate you and expect that my problem will be cleared.

I had built and scratched the adobe air desktop app (.air) for two years.
The app has been signed by the company official code signing certificate.
Today, the latest certificate is coming the expiration date.
Thus, I bought the new certificate.

If I sign the new build by only the new one, the user who use the latest signed app can not upgrade their app to the new signed app.
Because the latest certificate and new certificate conflicts between these apps.
I know the migrate command which is prepared by adobe, and this give me the way of duplicated signature,
This command should avoid the conflict above.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS13ACB483-1711-43c0-9049-0A7251630A7D.html

But this command doesn't work on my environment.

### I tested as below.

Normaly, migrates command can build duplicated signature, so I use this command.
-for new certificate
adt -package -storetype PKCS11 -providerName SunPKCS11-eToken -storepass Google5home -tsa none bat\temp.air application.xml -C bin .
-for latest certificate
adt -migrate -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "bat\rakuchinPrint2_2015.pfx" -storepass rakuchinprint2 -tsa none bat\temp.air air\rakuchinprint2.0.air

The air file was generated,then I tried to update the latest build.
First, I install the latest build.
Second, I install the new build to update(overwrite) the latest build.
But the air general install system panel said me the installation error by the certification conflict.

Are there any solution?
If there were the expert of adobe air, I would be glad to here form you.